# awk print 2 lines back if match

Tags: text-processing, awk, nawk

I have some output that looks like the following:

```
Gathering data for drive 1 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca17096
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs
Drive Temp:  41 C

Gathering data for drive 2 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca24156
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs
Drive Temp:  41 C

Gathering data for drive 3 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca8749
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
failed to get drive stats

Gathering data for drive 4 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca19183
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs
Drive Temp:  41 C

Gathering data for drive 5 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca4607
Drive Model: HUSMH8010BSS204
failed to get drive stats

Gathering data for drive 6 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca10152
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs
Drive Temp:  41 C
```

I would like to print the "Drive name" for any drive in which the drive stats cannot be returned (so matching on `failed to get drive stats`).

I know how to get the previous line with:

```
awk '$0=="failed to get drive stats" && $2>1 {print f} {f=$0}'
```

But that doesn't help me.

Desired output:

```
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca8749
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca4607
```

---

Edit:

For some reason when the output is redirected it doesn't appear the same way as it does on the terminal.  If I run:

```
command >out.txt 2>&1
```

The output file will look like:

```
failed to get drive stats
failed to get drive stats

Gathering data for drive 1 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca17096
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs
Drive Temp:  41 C

Gathering data for drive 2 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca24156
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs
Drive Temp:  41 C

....
```

Both awk answers provided work but I just have other issues I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -F ':' '$1 == "Drive name" { saved = $0 } $0 == "failed to get drive stats" { print saved }' file
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca8749
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca4607
```

This first sets the input field separator to a `:`. It then saves the line in the variable `saved` whenever a line specifying a drive name is found.

If a line says `failed to get drive stats`, the current value of `saved` is printed.

Comment: It's so strange because if I save the command output to a file this works but trying to read it through a pipe and it doesn't.  So it has nothing to do with the awk version

Comment: stderr is unbuffered but stdout is buffered - maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This is why awk has a "paragraph mode", all you need is:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/failed to get drive stats/{print $2}' file
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca8749
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca4607
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below method and it worked fine

```
awk '{a[++i]=$0}/failed/{for(x=NR-2;x<NR;x++)print a[x]}' filename| sed -n '1~2p'
```

output

```
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca8749
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca4607
```

Comment: Ask yourself what the difference is between `i` and `NR`. Now ask yourself why you need `i`. Now ask yourself why you're printing 2 lines at a time with a loop in awk and then deleting the 2nd line of every pair with sed. You also never need sed when you're using awk anyway.