# Print line if following line is missing

Tags: text-processing, awk, illumos, nawk

This is related to [awk print 2 lines back if match](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/562523/237982) but since my command has buffering issues that I'm unable to resolve I think a better approach would be to completely ignore stderr and look for output missing certain lines.

So my output will be:

```
Gathering drive descriptors ...
Gathering data for drive 0 ...
Drive Model: DataTraveler 2.0
Gathering data for drive 1 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca17096
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs
Drive Temp:  41 C

Gathering data for drive 2 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca24156
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs
Drive Temp:  41 C

Gathering data for drive 3 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca8749
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Gathering data for drive 4 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca19183
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs
Drive Temp:  41 C

Gathering data for drive 5 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca4607
Drive Model: HUSMH8010BSS204
Gathering data for drive 6 ...
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca10152
Drive Model: HUH721010AL4204
Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs
Drive Temp:  41 C
```

And I would like to output the `Drive name` for any drive missing the `Drive Speed` and `Drive Temp` lines.

Output should be:

```
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca8749
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca4607
```

This is beyond my capabilities but I'm sure `awk` can do it but am not set on using `awk`, anything that accomplishes the task will work (don't have GNU tools).  Thanks!

Comment: Also sorry but I've updated the output.  It appears when redirected the newlines between the bad drive sections get removed.

Comment: You mentioned something about buffering and something about different results if you redirect something (stdout? stderr? both?) to a file vs if you don't (pipe to a command?). You might want to ask a question about that specifically as the solution to whatever that problem is will probably make the solutions to your other questions clearer and simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `mawk` and `gawk`, which support regex and multi-character `RS` (record separators):

```
awk -v RS='Gathering data' -F'\n' '/Drive name/ && !/Drive Speed/ && !/Drive Temp/{print$(NF-2)}' file
```

With an `awk` which doesn't support them, the input could be filtered to replace it with some single character like form-feed:

```
awk '/Gathering data/{$0="\f"} 1' file | awk -v RS='\f' -F'\n' '/Drive name/ && !/Drive Speed/ && !/Drive Temp/{print$(NF-2)}'
```

If the lines within a record are not in a fixed order, whole records could be printed by omitting the `{print ...}`, and then output could be filtered with grep, etc.

This approach has the advantage that the matching condition could be modified in an obvious way (eg. `/Drive Speed: 7200 RPMs/` instead of `!/foo/ && !/bar/`, etc), that it doesn't load the whole file in the memory, and most importantly, doesn't require you to write some obtuse state machine.

Comment: With gawk, you can also set RS to the empty string: `-v RS= -v FS='\n'`

Comment: And now with the updated input, use `RS='Gathering data'`

Comment: @glennjackman thanks!

Comment: @mosvy, on my debian/bash, I pasted awk script, it printed `Model` line

Comment: @Philippe the OP has changed the original example input, and I had to change the original answer too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perl version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

perl -ne '
    $l = $_ if (/Drive name:/);
    $s = 1  if (/Drive Speed:/);
    if (/^\s*$/) {
        print "$l\n" if (! defined($s));
        $s = undef;
    }
' "$1"
```

Assuming there is an empty line at the end of input file.

Run with : test.sh file

Comment: FWIW this works so thanks! but unfortunately the awk solution is better suited for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

No need for multi-char `RS` if the fields' order can be relied upon:

```
awk '/Drive name/ {if (!LCNT && OLDNM) print OLDNM; OLDNM = $3; LCNT = 0} /Drive (Speed|Temp)/ {LCNT++}' file3
id1,sd@n5000cca8749
id1,sd@n5000cca4607
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have tag/name and value pairs in your data it's best to create/use an array that mimics that in your code. Similarly when you have blocks of multi-line records. In your previous question I showed you how to handle that when your records are blank-line separated (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562552/133219), here's how to do it when they aren't and how to use the more general tag-val approach rather than relying on the position of each value in the record:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=": *" }
/^Gathering data/ { prt() }
{ tags2vals[$1] = $0 }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( ("Drive name" in tags2vals) && ( !("Drive Speed" in tags2vals) || !("Drive Temp" in tags2vals) ) ) {
        print tags2vals["Drive name"]
    }
    delete tags2vals
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca8749
Drive name:  id1,sd@n5000cca4607
```