# How to change \n to space and \n\n to \n by sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, video-subtitles

I use `sed` to convert an `srt` file to a regular text file. `An`srt` file has a format of

```
1
00:20:41,150 --> 00:20:45,109
line 1
line 2

2
00:21:41,150 --> 00:21:45,109
line 3
line 4
```

So I use the following command to remove non-text lines

```
sed -r '/^[0-9]+$/{N;d}' file.srt > file.txt
```

which produces

```
line1
line2

line3
line4
```

but I want to get

```
line1 line2
line3 line4
```

(each subtitle segment as a single line)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using `awk`, by operating it in "paragraph mode" (see e.g. @EdMorton's solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562552/377345) and a solution to the "print all but the first fields" problem [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457486/print-rest-of-the-fields-in-awk))

```
awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{$1=$2=""; print $0}' file.srt > file.txt
```

This will interpret any blocks of "empty line"-separated text as one input record, whose fields are the individual lines of the text block. The above command will then replace the first two fields (=lines) by the "empty" string and print the entire line.

NB that this leaves two spaces (the output field separator) before the "actual output". If this is a problem, you can explicitly print only the remaining fields with an `awk`-internal loop:

```
awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{for (i=3; i<NF; i++) printf("%s ",$i); printf("%s\n",$NF)}' file.srt > file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

use this to get your pattern

```
sed ':begin;$!N;s/\n/ /;tbegin' file.txt | sed 's/  /\n/g'
```